# Difficulty with using an overloaded addition operator

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, operator-keyword, addition

So here is my program. I have to make an object of type Student, then have the Student "check out" an item. And I am using an overloaded addition operator to make the user check out that item.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Student s(54000, "JOHN", "DOE");

    cout << "main:" << endl << (s + "Frisbee") << endl << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

I defined all my class defintions in the header file to try and keep this program minimal and simplified.

Student.h:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student {

public:

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
    int itemsCheckedOut;
    int size;
    string *array;

    Student(int id = 0, string firstName = "", string lastName = "") {
        Student::firstName = firstName;
        Student::lastName = lastName;
        Student::id = id;
        itemsCheckedOut = 0;
        size = 10;
        array = new string[size];
    }

    Student(const Student &other) {
        itemsCheckedOut = other.itemsCheckedOut;
        array = new string[itemsCheckedOut];
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCheckedOut; i++) {
            array[i] = other.array[i];
        }
    }

    ~Student() {
        delete[] array;
        array = NULL;
    }

    Student &operator=(const Student &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            firstName = rhs.firstName;
            lastName = rhs.lastName;
            id = rhs.id;
            itemsCheckedOut = rhs.itemsCheckedOut;
            delete[] array;
            array = new string[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCheckedOut; i++) {
                array[i] = rhs.array[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void CheckOut(const string &item) {
        array[itemsCheckedOut] = item;
        itemsCheckedOut++;
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Student &student) {
        output << student.id << "  " << student.firstName << " " << student.lastName << endl;
        if (student.itemsCheckedOut != 0) {
            output << student.itemsCheckedOut;
            for (int i = 0; i < student.itemsCheckedOut; i++) {
                output << " " << student.array[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        else {
            output << 0;
        }
        return output;
    }

    const Student operator+(const string &item) {
        Student s;
        s = *this;
        s.CheckOut(item);
        cout << "class:" << endl << s << endl << endl;
        return s;
    }

};

#endif
```

output:

```
class:
54000  JOHN DOE
1 Frisbee

main:
-858993460
1 Frisbee
```

As you can see, from the main, its outputting the wrong thing. Instead of outputting the id followed by two spaces then the first name and last name, it outputs the number: -858993460. This has gotta be some sort of memory leak issue or something, but I'm pretty sure my copy constructor, overloaded assignment operator, and deconstructor are all defined correctly, but you can take a look at them.

I would appreciate any help at all as I am getting pretty desperate here. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls copy constructor:

```
    Student(const Student &other) {
    itemsCheckedOut = other.itemsCheckedOut;
    array = new string[itemsCheckedOut];
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCheckedOut; i++) {
        array[i] = other.array[i];
    }
}
```

but you forget to copy all Student's fields in its body.
You override default copy constructor, so you should manually execute all data copying, as in assignment operator.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't catch this. I guess I just thought the copy constructor was supposed to be only used for dynamic arrays or something. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your actual `operator+` looks correct. But there are bugs in your copy-constructor and assignment-operator that would cause it to malfunction:

- The copy-constructor does not set `size`, `id`, or the names.
- The copy-constructor should allocate `[size]` items, not `[itemsCheckedOut]`.
- The assignment operator does not copy `size`.
- The assignment operator allocates a new array whose dimension is the old size, probably causing an immediate buffer overflow.
- The checkOut function does not check that it doesn't write beyond `size`. It needs to detect this case and either reject the checkout, or allocate more space. (I mentioned this last time you posted a question about this project)

Comment: Thanks for the help @M.M. And yea, I do need to add some functionality to detect when the CheckOut is about to write beyond the size. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your string* array with a std::vector. It will handle the memory management for you, make your code far easier and less error prone than the manual memory management you are currently using. You can reserve an initial size of 10 if you are worried about it doing allocations when adding items (although with such small data sizes that shouldn't ever be a problem).

Comment: This is an assignment for one of my classes at school and it was laid out in the guidelines that I must use a dynamic string array.

Comment: @Jacob If you are good with words and your teacher has sense of humor tell him, that std::vector internally has dynamic array, so you are using one although indirectly :) .

Comment: Lol, if only it was that easy... :P But really, I want to figure out how to make it work with a dynamic string array. I have no idea why it's doing this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @M.M Do you have any idea why that whenever I output the class in the overloaded addition operator that it outputs correctly, but when I output the return value of the class in the main, it doesn't output correctly?

Comment: @Jacob yes, see my answer